# Kovan transaction never being mined

Tags: web3js, javascript, infura

I have setup an Infura account to send transactions on the kovan network.
This is the code I want to use to send ether to another account (current one has 1 ether from a faucet):

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/<PI>');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');








target='<target address>'
priv='<priv key>'
address= '<from address>'
a=web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(priv);

web3.eth.defaultAccount =address

const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const privateKey = Buffer.from(
    priv,

  'hex',
)

price=20_000_000_000
limit=21000

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x199',
  gasPrice: "0x"+price.toString(16),
  gasLimit: "0x"+limit.toString(16),
  to: target,
  value: "0x100",
}
// The second parameter is not necessary if these values are used
const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams)
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();


web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
.on('receipt', console.log);


console.log("success")
```

But the transaction never gets mined, no matter how high I set the gas limit. I eventually get this message

```
(node:28855) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/<PK>`, I sincerely hope that `PK` stands for your project ID and not for your private key.

Comment: Also, is this for real: `"0x"+Math.floor( price ).toString(16)`??? First of all, `price` is initially set to an integer value of `5000000000`, so what exactly is the point in passing it to `Math.floor`? Second, what exactly is the point in prepending `0x`??? You may as well just use a price of `0x5000000000`. This is going to be quite a very high price, are you sure you're good for it?

Comment: Third, what exactly is the idea behind configuring `gasLimit` as a function of the value of `price`???

Comment: Fourth, I'm pretty sure that `1000000000000000000` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is equal to 2 ^ 53 - 1. So you'd be better off not using it as a number, but rather as a BigNmuber or BN object (depending on what web3 version your own). Then, I suppose that you might need to convert the result into a string before passing it to `new EthereumTx`.

Comment: the reason for math floor is for if I use decimal division. I got 50000 from we3.eth.getGasPrice(). I wanted to set the gas limit as 0.035 eth so I could set that directly, so I divieded it by the gas price. I think the transaction is passed to the blockchain, it just doesn't have enough gas to be mined I think

Comment: With `price=5000000000`, the value return by `Math.floor( price )` is... `5000000000`!

Comment: And with regards to "it just doesn't have enough gas to be mined I think" - As I wrote in the third comment, what exactly is the idea behind configuring `gasLimit` as a function of the value of `price`??? It needs to be set according to the contract function which you are trying to execute. Or if you're just trying to transfer ether, then it should be 21000 (or slightly more, depending on the destination address). But most certainly not something like `wei*0.05/price`.

Comment: Can you give me a value for gasLimit and gasPrice that should most likely work so I can verify that my node is working properly? I have 1 eth on the account.

Comment: If `target` is not the address of a contract, then you can set `gasLimit` to `21000`. If it is the address of a contract, then you should set it to slightly higher than that. Regarding `gasPrice` - set it according to how fast you want your transaction to get executed.

Comment: So what would be a good number for fast?

Comment: Depending on the network. You can try 20gwei I suppose.

Comment: I changed the code to what it says in the post, yet I still get the same error; the transaction was not mined in 50 blocks. Am I still doing something wrong?